# Как организовать удобное хранение текстов для уведомлений в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

**Ситуация:** на сервисе есть система уведомлений, её цель схожа с Майлером - уведомление пользователей о чём-либо, но внутри сервиса. Yii2 Advanced.

**Проблема:** если размещать текст в коде - это его "загромождает" и делает трудным для чтения, особенно после использования ещё и функции интернационализации. Да и, собственно, обширному тексту там нечего делать.

Пример:

```
$this->noticeService->add(
    $event->ticket->user_id,
    "Ответ в тикете: " . $event->ticket->subject,
    "Вам поступил ответ от поддержке в тикете: " . Html::a($event->ticket->subject, $link),
    'life-ring',
    'info'
);
```

**Вопрос**: есть ли какой-либо функционал фреймворка, чтобы разместить тексты в папке, аля @common\notification, как в письмах с Mailer'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нотисы генерятся с помощью view, то можно сделать шаблон и несколько вьюшек. Текст хранить во вьюшках. Получится темплейт для уведомления и на каждый тип уведомления уже свой файл с текстом. В другом случае хранить текст в БД (удобно редактировать) и кешировать его, чтобы часто не дергать базу. Тогда просто формируем массив и дергаем нужный текст по ключу.

Если текст хранить в файлах, то я бы разделил все уведомления по типам и на каждый тип сделал свой класс со своим текстом. А потом уже в зависимости от типа вызываем нужный класс, передаем в него сервис и данные для добавления уведомления.

```
SupportNotice::execute($this->noticeService, $event, $otherParams);
```

А в экзекуте уже получаем сервис и дергаем метод add()